# how to add row in temporary table data table in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datatable, viewstate

```
protected void Add_New_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {



            DataTable dt= new DataTable();

            DataRow dr;
            dr = dt.NewRow();


            string CustomerID = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCustomerID")).Text;
            string CustomerName = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCustomerName")).Text;
            string CustomerFatherName = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCustomerFatherName")).Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            ViewState["sajjad_Viewstate"] = dt;


        }
```

Comment: CustomerId CustomerName variables showing me data but problem is that is showing null values in data table, how to add ? please help me

Comment: Anybody help me ? why its showing null values ?

Comment: You don't seem to be assigning the CustomerID and CustomerName variable values back into datacolumns of the datarow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void Add_New_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {



            DataTable dt= new DataTable();
         // Add columns here
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CustomerID"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CustomerName"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CustomerFatherName"));
            //Create new row
            DataRow dr= dt.NewRow();


            string CustomerID = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCustomerID")).Text;
            string CustomerName = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCustomerName")).Text;
            string CustomerFatherName = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCustomerFatherName")).Text;
            //populate columns with data

            dr["CustomerID"] = CustomerID;
            dr["CustomerID"] = CustomerName;
            dr["CustomerFatherName"] = CustomerFatherName;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            ViewState["sajjad_Viewstate"] = dt;


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        dt.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = txtitemname.Text;
        dr[1] = txtitemcode.Text;
        dr[2] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtprice.Text);
        dr[3] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtqty.Text);
        dr[4] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtamount.Text);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        ViewState["DtItem"] = dt;
    }
    else
    {
        dt = (DataTable)ViewState["DtItem"];
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = txtitemname.Text;
        dr[1] = txtitemcode.Text;
        dr[2] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtprice.Text);
        dr[3] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtqty.Text);
        dr[4] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtamount.Text);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        ViewState["DtItem"] = dt;
    }
    grditem.DataSource =(DataTable)ViewState["DtItem"];
```